# Permission Check across multiple abp.io projects

Tags: abp, abp.io, abp-framework

I am using multiple abp.io (7.3.3) projects with all of them authenticating against a single identity project. Below is an example of the structure

Project A - Microservices Tiered Project with API, Identity and Web projects
Project B - Tiered project with API and Web. Identity server is set to Project A
Project C - Tiered project with API and Web. Identity server is set to Project A

All projects have their own dedicated client id and secret created in project A.

It is all working fine. The issue is when i want to assign specific permissions to modules in Project B and C. I have the necessary permissions configured in Project A and when i debug the user in B and C, i can see the permission has been assigned.

In B and C, context.IsGrantedAsync("ThePermissionName") will always return false. I have also created the same permission in B and C just to be sure.

Is there a different way to check for permissions? Am i missing something on the authorisation middleware?